# ActionCable-5.2.2 not working in nginx and puma broken pipe error using JRUBY 9.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5.2

**The project works perfectly on nginx and passenger, but it does not work with puma and nginx.**

Here's the puma error(No nginx error so far):

```
warning: thread "Ruby-0-Thread-82: /home/deploy/app/current/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.2/lib/action_cable/connection/stream_event_loop.rb:75" terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):


ArgumentError: mode not supported for this object: r
         register at org/nio4r/Selector.java:123
  block in attach at /home/deploy/app/current/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.2/lib/action_cable/connection/stream_event_loop.rb:31
     block in run at /home/deploy/app/current/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.2/lib/action_cable/connection/stream_event_loop.rb:93
             loop at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1418
              run at /home/deploy/app/current/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.2/lib/action_cable/connection/stream_event_loop.rb:86
   block in spawn at /home/deploy/app/current/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.2/lib/action_cable/connection/stream_event_loop.rb:75
```

Here's the configurations so far:

nginx/sites_enabled/sitetest.com

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///tmp/my_app-puma.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sitetest.com;


    location ^~ /assets/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
    location @puma {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_pass http://puma;
    }

    location /cable {
      proxy_pass http://puma;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Production.rb

```
config.action_cable.url = 'wss://sitetest.com/cable'
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'https://sitetest.com' ]
```

Rails console logs:

```
 Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 103.10.28.154 at 2019-01-27 18:10:10 +0000
 Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
 WebSocket error occurred: Broken pipe -
```

It should be related to [Argument Error In ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31517)
**The link suggests to update nio4r gem to 2.2 or above but actioncable 5.2.2 uses nio4r 2.0.**